# How to get client side html date from server side with yyyymmdd format

Tags: html, asp.net

How to get client side html date from server side with yyyymmdd format.

Following html code is for capturing date.

```
<input type="date"  id="dtpdob" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Date of Birth" name="dtpdob"  />
```

Following server side code I am using to change the date format. But it is now working.

```
dim ddob as string=Format(dtpdob.Value, "yyyyMMdd")
```

Please help how can I change the date format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the format use you have ONLY works if the input is a date - and NOT a string.

So, you can cast the value to date - and then format can be used.

eg

```
    Dim ddob As String = Format(CDate(dtpdob.Value), "yyyyMMdd")
```

So format requires a date value, and if you feed format a string - it will not work.

And the "value" from that control is of course a string.